# Получение имени объекта из самого объекта?

Tags: c#, объекты

Здравствуйте! 
Анонимные типы дают имя объекта. А что если мне нужно например записать что то в свойство этого объекта и одновременно в этом свойстве заполнить другое поле именем этого объекта, но когда я пишу

```
{
    x = value; 
    y = GetVariableName(new { this}); 
}

static string GetVariableName<T>(T variable) 
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].Name;
}
```

то в поле y он записывает не имя объекта а имя первого поля этого объекта. Скажи пожалуйста как в поле y записать имя этого объекта?

Comment: - Что в вашей терминологии означает *имя объекта*? Анонимный тип - это тип с замангленным непроизносимым именем и в большинстве случаев набором пропертей. Какой **имя** вы хотите записать в `property` `'y'`?

- `GetProperties()` действительно вернуло вам список пропертей, все в соответствии с заголовком функции.

Comment: @Котик: думаю, наличие имени у анонимного типа -- подробность реализации, не гарантируемая стандартом. (Документацию не проверял, каюсь.)

Comment: На тот случай, если мало ли кто-нибудь будет интересоваться тем, как выглядят анонимные типы в варианте от мелкомягких: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483023/how-to-test-if-a-type-is-anonymous

Comment: {
MyClass Name = new MyClass(); 
}

Котик_хочет_кушать, имя объекта в моей терминологии это Name.)) Извиняюсь если непонятно выражаюсь. Был бы очень благодарен если бы вы помогли мне найти ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @СуперАлексей

- Это *имя переменной.* Достучаться до него в момент выполнения приложения нельзя даже через `Reflection,` поскольку нет гарантии, что эта переменная вообще будет присутствовать в `IL` коде.

- Единственное исключение - это использование `Expression Trees.` Я, конечно, сомневаюсь, что это ваш случай, но для них [**это возможно.**](http://goo.gl/NHI5h)